# How to reference object in class view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

In my models, I have both tasks and projects. What I'm trying to do is add related tasks into the context of the page in which projects are updated.

The error I'm getting is:

> type object 'project' has no attribute 'id'

In models.py I have the task class:

```
class task(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    .... 
    related_project = models.ForeignKey(project, blank=True, null=True)
```

Also in models.py, I have the project class:

```
class project(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...
```

The view I'm using to update the Project object is:

```
class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    """
    This will be used to view and update projects
    """
    template_name = 'tasks/update-project.html'
    model = project
    fields = ['name','status', 'purpose', 'vision', 'big_steps', 'context', 'priority', 'due_date', 'related_project']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This puts the tasks related to the particular project in context
        """
        # Call base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ProjectUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # TO DO: Add in querysets of related tasks
        context = context['related_tasks'] = task.objects.filter(related_project__id=project.id)
```

The problem seems to be that "project.id" does not actually access the "id" of the particular project object. How to I add the tasks that are linked to the particular project object being updated via the task's "related_project" attribute (which has as a foreign key the project object)?

Comment: Before I delete my answer.. is your problem with getting the specific instance being shown or how to actually access the id?

Comment: you might want to start by following pep8 guidelines and give your class a capital letter (`Project`)

Comment: How to access the id generally. That is, generally speaking, how would I access the id of the whichever project object would show up in the ProjectUpdate view.

Comment: I've undeleted my answer for the time being to show 3 ways to solve that issue, although I think the actual problem may be due to not actually calling an instance of `project`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `project.id` because `project` is the model, not the instance you are updating. Normally you would call your model `Project` and a model instance `project`. Calling your model `project` will confuse other users, as they'll assume it's an instance instead of a model.

In the `get_context_data` method, you can access the object with `self.object`.

```
context['related_tasks'] = task.objects.filter(related_project__id=self.object.id)
```

Make sure you don't set `context = context['related_tasks'] = ...`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked, and I have changed the model capitalization as you suggested.